# PHP program is negating a function?

Tags: php, syntax, authentication, logic

So basically what I have set up here is a very simple and generic log in. I have the entire code copy and pasted because maybe its important somehow. However-

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['User']);
$pass = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['Pass']));
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error());
(mysql_select_db('fireworks', $conn));
$ask = "SELECT * FROM name WHERE (User = '" . $user . "') and (Pass = '" . $pass . "');";
$result = mysql_query($ask);
```

The segment of code below is completely ignored! When I press log in (From the index page) It is suppose to run a series of checks. If the user decides to not put anything inside the user and password text boxes then it is suppose to return the string show below:

```
if (strlen($user) < 1){
    if (strlen($pass) < 1){
        print "<p class = 'Back'>Epic Fail</p>";
        print "<p>You forgot to put in your Username or Password.</p>";
    }
}
```

(^Up until here) But it doesn't. Instead its just a blank page. But everything else works fine. If I type in a fake user then it returns "YOU FAIL!" If I type a valid user it returns "WELCOME BACK."

```
if (strlen($user) >= 1){
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            print "<p class='Back'>Welcome back</p><p>" . $row['User'] . "</p>";
        }
    }else{
        print "YOU FAIL!!!";
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? EXTRA NOTES: The database is called fireworks the table is called name there are three columns in the name table. nameID, User, and Pass. (Idk how this is useful but sometimes it is.)

Comment: are you checking what the value of strlen($user) is? Maybe it's not less than 1

Comment: you should indent your code: it would make it a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```
if (strlen($user) < 1){
if (strlen($pass) < 1){
print "<p>You forgot to put in your Username or Password.</p>";
}
}
```

In actual fact, this won't check for `$user` or `$pass` being blank; it will only give the error message if **both** of them are blank.

Each test is okay on its own, but the way it's written, the test for `$pass` will only be run if the `$user` test has already given a `true` result.

What you need to to is write them together with an `or` condition, like so:

```
if (strlen($user) < 1 or strlen($pass) < 1){
....
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. That is so much less confusing and popular compared to the pipe symbol method everyone else gave me.

Comment: PHP accepts either the word `or` or the double pipe `||` for this. They both do exactly the same thing. (most experienced programmers do prefer the double pipe, and there are some very subtle differences between them, but in this context those differences are irrelevant)

Comment: Note that if `$pass` is `md5($_POST['Pass'])`, `$pass` will never be an empty string; even an empty string has a hash.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
if (strlen($user) < 1 || strlen($pass) < 1){ .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're nesting the ifs, so the "Epic Fail" is only displayed when both the user name and password aren't entered.

You might want to change it to this:

```
if (strlen($user) < 1 || strlen($pass) < 1)
{
    print "<p class = 'Back'>Notice</p>";
    print "<p>You forgot to put in your Username or Password.</p>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) it says that it will attempt to connect to database for the character set. If you did not connect to database at all before the check it might very well be the case. You can check if error reporting to see if it returned `E_WARNING` level error.

Another thing is that you should avoid database calls when it is not needed. If thats the whole part of the important code, you should call both checks before you try to escape them and continue with database stuff. Also, `empty()` function might help you as well.

```
if(!empty($_POST['User']) || trim(strlen($_POST['User'])) < 1) {
 // database stuff
}
```

Comment: you mean: `strlen(trim($pass)) < 1)`